# matrix isomorphism apparent contradiction - where is the bug?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M_2(\mathbb R)$ be the algebra of 2x2 matrices over $\mathbb R$.
Let $M^{op}_2$ be the same algebra, but with product reverted (that is,
$A\cdot B \ \hbox{(in $M^{op}$)}= B\cdot A \ \hbox{(in $M$)}$.

By the Skolem-Noether theorem (if I'm not wrong), every isomorphism of $M$ into $M^{op}$ is
of the form $f(M) = U^{-1}MU$, where $U$ is an invertible matrix of $M_2$ (depending only on $f$).

Now, matrix transposition is such an isomorphism. But I think that if there were exist a matrix $U$ such that $M^T= U^{-1}MU$ for all $M$, this would be known (a joke, this is impossible of course).

So, the theorem of Skolem-Noether is false!
where is the bug in my thinking ?

**Edit**: the Skolem-Noether theorem:
Let $R$, $S$ be finite dimensional algebras, $R$ simple and $S$ central simple. If $f, g :\ R → S$ are homomorphisms then there is an element $s ∈ S$ such that, for all $r ∈ R$, $g(r) = s^{−1} f (r)s$.

Comment: The Skolem-Noether theorem tells you (under certain conditins) that any two homomorphisms are conjugate. When applied to $f, \operatorname{id} \colon M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to M_2(\mathbb{R})$, you get that any isomorphism of $ M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is inner. But when you take $f \colon M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to M_2^{\textrm{op}}(\mathbb{R})$ to be the transpose map, you cannot compare it to $\operatorname{id}$ as $\operatorname{id}$ is no longer a homomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Your statment cannot possibly be true, since $M\mapsto U^{-1}MU$ is *not* a ring homomorphism from $M$ onto $M^{\text{op}}$; it does not reverse the order.

Comment: Regarding your first statement, see my edit. Regarding your second statement, I chose $f = Id$, but Id is indeed not an homomorphism - you have probably the point!

Comment: You are right; I only stated a particular case of the theorem.